# How to handle bulk api request in a nodejs server?

Tags: node.js, request, digital-ocean

Its a suggestion based question.

I am developing a server for Algo trading through Kite Api from Zerodha.

Here I have a few thousand clients who will join the system, In this process I have to place order for every client with different `api_key`, `api_secret` and `access_token`, and every request has different data from the exchange. Now I am worried about if I make request with credentials in a loop then it may consume a lot of time, How can I perform all the request at lightning speed from a single server ?

Number of clients will increase by time to time

I am using Digitalocean droplet for this job.

If any one can suggest the best solution It will be a great help for my project.

Comment: Hi Mijanur, Were you able to figure out? I'm having similar scenario and looking for some hints.

Comment: @sharmag its not figured out yet, hence I have postponed the project, In my knowledge I need to use a looping call on async function or api

Comment: Hello @MijanurRahaman
I had worked this type of system you have to use the socket for real-time orders. and access_token you have to generate every 8 AM. ( Which is also create using python script automated ) so don;t worries about it.